# Issue with margins when markup is added with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, margin

For some reason, if I add these buttons with jQuery (because of an Ajax insert function) they look strange to when they are loaded via PHP on the server?

[http://tomsfil.es/63221c41.png http://tomsfil.es/63221c41.png](http://tomsfil.es/63221c41.png)

What is the reason for this behavior

Here is the jQuery that inserts it:

```
var actions = '<td><a href="#" class="small awesome black editButton" id="'+id+'">Edit</a><a href="/appointments/new/'+id+'/" class="small awesome black">Schedule</a><a href="#" class="small awesome red deleteButton" id="'+id+'">Delete</a></td>';
$('.clients tr.headerRow').after("<tr>"+check+"<td>#"+id+"</td>"+name+address+homephone+actions+"</tr>");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to guess that because you have organized code, each button is on a new line, meaning there is a space in between them. When you add it via js, is there a space between each button?

Answer (score 1):

**Update 1**

```
<tr>"+check+"<td>#"+id+"</td>"+name+address+homephone+actions+"</tr>
```

You're inserting values between `<tr>` and a nested `<td>`. This is a no-no. Values need to be *within* the `<td>` tags.

--

You ought to examine the old markup vs dynamically-added markup via firebug. It's likely that your structures are either slightly different, or that a class attribute is not being applied properly to the new elements due to a typo, or an overridden style.

For a more helpful answer, provide your initial markup, and the code that inserts the new markup as well as any CSS that may be affected the elements.

Comment: hmm yeah well its exactly the same :|

Comment: @tarnfield: It's not *exactly* the same, or else you wouldn't have rendering differences.

Answer (score 0):

It's only the first white-space between HTML elements that matter. Not having any space at all is different to having 1-* spaces.